# Develop using angular and mock all json request/responses

Tags: json, angularjs

Is it possible for me to develop the entire front-end of a website using angularjs before I develop the backend services that will perform the actual json request/responses? i.e. the crud operations that persist to the database etc.

Can someone provide some insight on how to do this?

Comment: Use static json data in place of what would be a json request? You should have an idea of what your service will eventually return

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by using localStorage services and swapping them out for actual services as the REST APIs become available.

Here is an example of how one could implement a localStorage service:

```
app.factory('user', function($rootScope) {

  var userJson = window.localStorage['appUser'];

  var user = userJson ? JSON.parse(userJson) : {
    username: undefined,
    password: undefined
  };

  $rootScope.$watch(function() { return user; }, function() {
    window.localStorage['appUser'] = JSON.stringify(user);
  }, true);

  return user;
});
```

For more information on this approach, check out Igor Minár's [FoodMe app](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme).

Comment: Cool, but how does one define some initial mock data for such a service/factory? Like if I wanted to load some test users in my app?

Comment: I found this article: http://flippinawesome.org/2013/09/09/mocking-server-dependencies-in-javascript-and-angularjs/ -- very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project currently where I had to accomplish the same thing.  There are several options, including hardcoding the JSON or referencing it from localstorage.  I decided to take another approach by making a $http.get() call to a static json file, so all I would need to do is replace the hardcoded json file, with my REST service call upon its completion.

```
return $http.get('example.json').then(function(result) {
            /* ... Stuff on success ... */
        },
        function(result){
            /* ... Stuff on failure ... */
        }
```

Comment: So angularjs usings $http.get for all requests?  you just modified it to link to a file that returns json, but what is runid?  you might have 10's of different calls, so each call gets its own static file?

Comment: I setup a $http.get for each REST web service call I would eventually need.  This simply satisfied my requirement and could be different for your situation.  While the web services were in development I created a hardcoded JSON response to simulate the REST response.  The "RunId" was just an example from my code.

Comment: @ral8 I like this approach. I'm running an Angular app and proxying my requests through Sinatra. I'm fetching json files from the public folder but I'm wondering, is it a security issue to have publicly accessible json files containing the structure for my application?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend). It is a mocking framework specifically designed for end-to-end tests using angularJS, but it can also be used to completely mock a REST API.

The advantage of using this framework is that you will need very few changes in your frontend code when switching to a real backend. You just switch the ng-app tag and remove the references to the mock scripts, and that's it. And you can of course reuse the same mock API in your end-to-end tests. The downside (as opposed to using local storage) is that all modified data will disappear when refreshing the page (reloading the angularJS app), but that isn't really a problem if you are developing a true single page web application where you don't do page refreshes anyway.